# warning: '__builtin_snprintf' output may be truncated before the last format character [-Wformat-truncation=]

Tags: c, gcc-warning, gcc11

```
warning: ‘__builtin_snprintf’ output may be truncated before the last format character [-Wformat-truncation=]
  "%s", evspan->text);
     ^

len = strlen(evspan->text);
evspan->ent->content = malloc(len+1);

snprintf(evspan->ent->content, len,
"%s", evspan->text);
```

I saw this warning on gcc 8. How do I prevent this without using -Wformat-truncation option?

Comment: Whats the point of using `snprintf` in this code? `strcpy` has the same result.

Comment: Don't use `snprintf()` when `strcpy()` or `memmove()` (or `memcpy()`) would be safe and sensible.  I assume you do check the return value from `malloc()` to protect against memory shortages.

Comment: Better yet, just use `strdup`.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/ooEx8Psdz) - please make a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `snprintf` is the length of the buffer, not the maximum string length.

The call should be:

```
snprintf(evspan->ent->content, len + 1, "%s", evspan->text);
```

This matches the length passed to `malloc`.

---

The comments given on `snprintf` not being the best choice do apply, if your full code is as simple as what's shown here.